# Type error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' or its corresponding type declarations when deploying in Vercel

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs and firebase app setup with functions and everything runs and builds perfectly locally. However when I build and deploy to Vercel I get the following build error in Vercel console:

> Type error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' or its corresponding type declarations.

[image]

here's my app/functions package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and try to reinstall the `npm` packages?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB no I haven't. I ended up just adding `//@ts-ignore` comments above each line but will try your method

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when running `next build` locally?

Comment: @juliomalves no it works fine locally when running `next build` and serving

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by modifying the file `tsconfig.json`. I added "functions" to the "exclude" array.

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", "functions"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Given that functions are built and deployed separately by ```firebase deploy```, that should be fine to exclude them on project level..

Comment: This is a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `.vercelignore` file at the project's root and adding the Firebase functions directory (e.g. /firebaseFunctions don't forget the slash) resolved this issue for me.

Comment: I very much like this answer. Did also think about adding the `functions` into the `tsconfig.json` but this approach can have side-effects. For the purpose of ignoring things on the Vercel platform, I think it's best to just do that.

So: 
1. Create a new file `.vercelignore` in the project root
2. Add the things in that Vercel should ignore `functions/`
3. Add `.vercelignore` in your repo